# PfSense(on ESXi) on hetzner, IP Subnet not working

Tags: vmware-esxi, pfsense, hetzner

i have one primary IP of Hetzner DS(with ESXi on it, and pfsense). i got a subnet of /29 from hetzner. they say that the subnet IPs must route through Primary IP address of server, like if server IP is 1.1.1.5 then my subnet 2.2.2.2/29 must have gateway set to 1.1.1.5. (pfsense has IP set as 1.1.1.10)

Primary IP has settings as 1.1.1.5/32(ESX server main IP), with gateway 1.1.1.45 as gateway. When i added the subnet 2.2.2.2/29 in pfsense as virtual IP, i could not use any of them. I tried to add another interface in pfsense and add those subnets, but they overlap with previous gateway and other interfaces.

I tried to create new interface in pfsense (gave it no IP address) then on that interface, behind it, (as switch) i added one VM behind that switch, gave it IP 2.2.2.3/29 and gave it gateway 1.1.1.5, using so i can access all other IP, but cannot have internet access.

What cold be solution to this problem?

Comment: Their instruction is misleading, a subnet in 2.2.2.x cant have a gateway in the 1.1.1.1, it must be in the 1.1.1.x range. As such your pfsense must have a ip in the 1.1.1.x and a second interface in the 2.2.2.X for it’s LAN

Comment: my pfsense has IP: 95.x.x.6 , ESX has IP: 95.x.x.25 , my subnet is 95.x.x.152/29